# Ошибка "JFTP: :write: Некорректный ответ"

Tags: joomla

Не могу сохранить изменения в шаблоне, когда нажимаю на сохранить, выскакивают 2 сообщения

> JFTP: :write: Некорректный ответ.
>
> Не удалось сохранить данные. Ошибка: Произошла ошибка. Файл index.php не удаётся сохранить.

Это происходит, когда я пытаюсь изменить страницу главного шаблона или файлы:

`css/layouts.css
css/modules.css
css/template.css`

Comment: Может просто у вас нету прав на запись?

Comment: как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про **chmod**, [тут](http://advancedhosters.com/ru/chmod) в картинках. Более подробно - **man chmod** или [тут](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Chmod).

Comment: спасибо ща почитаю

Comment: а где можно найти файл chmod&